# Oracle "invalid format" when working with Date

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I've used SQL Server for years but I'm new to Oracle SQL. I'm trying to refactor an old application and one of the things I'm doing is moving it to the newer Oracle Managed Data Access. The application uses all in-line SQL with parameters.

I'm having an issue with the a query that deals with dates. I know Oracle expects dates to be in a specific format but I thought if I used the `TO_DATE` function I could work with whatever format I use.

When I try to run the following query with parameters I'm getting an error

> One of the identified items was in an invalid format

I'm assuming it's with the date piece.

If I use LinqPad and run the following query it will update just fine.

```
update SAP_DATES 
set DATE_VALUE = TO_DATE('2010-03-26','yyyy-mm-dd'), 
    DATE_MODIFIED = TO_DATE('2015-06-12','yyyy-mm-dd')  
where 
    EMP = '00000197' and DATE_TYPE = 'Retirement Date     '
```

However, if I use the following I get the following I get the error. I can confirm the date values right before calling the SQL being in a 'yyyy-mm-dd' format. No hours or minutes.

```
 public const String UPDATE_DATE_RECORD_SQL = "update SAP_DATES set " +
            "DATE_VALUE = TO_DATE(:dtValue,'yyyy-mm-dd'), DATE_MODIFIED = TO_DATE(:dtModified,'yyyy-mm-dd') " + 
            "where EMP = :Emp and DATE_TYPE = :dtType";
```

and in the data layer

```
using (objConnection)
{
    OracleCommand objCmd = objConnection.CreateCommand();
    objCmd.CommandText = oracleCmdText;

    objCmd.Parameters.Add(":Emp", OracleDbType.Varchar2).Value = employeeId;
    objCmd.Parameters.Add(":dtType", OracleDbType.Varchar2).Value = dtType;
    objCmd.Parameters.Add(":dtValue", OracleDbType.Date).Value = dtValue;
    objCmd.Parameters.Add(":dtModified", OracleDbType.Date).Value = dtModified;

    objConnection.Open();
    objCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Anyone know why I can run the query using LinqPad but if I use the in-line SQL with parameters I get the error?

Comment: `:dtValue` and `:dtModified` should be of type `Varchar2` because `TO_DATE` is expecting a string in the specified format for conversion into a date.

Comment: Perfect! That was the issue. Post this as an answer and I can give you the credit for it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`:dtValue` and `:dtModified` should be of type `Varchar2` because `TO_DATE` is expecting a string in the specified format for conversion into a date.-

Answer (score 1):

The order in which you add the parameters should be in the same order in which you have defined the update query in your sql statement

So use this order

```
     objCmd.Parameters.Add(":dtValue", OracleDbType.Date).Value = dtValue;
     objCmd.Parameters.Add(":dtModified", OracleDbType.Date).Value = dtModified;
     objCmd.Parameters.Add(":Emp", OracleDbType.Varchar2).Value = employeeId;
     objCmd.Parameters.Add(":dtType", OracleDbType.Varchar2).Value = dtType;
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but unfortunately that didn't seem to make a difference. It was my understanding that when you alias the parameter with a name it shouldn't matter the order but then again I'm new to Oracle so I could be wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I have that problem and in my case, it was not caused by the `Date` type, but caused 
by the oracle database binding attributes by position, and you need to bind by name...

```
oracleCommand.BindByName = true
```

Comment: This applies if working with the `Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client` namespace. A headache for my recent conversion from .NET 3 to 4.7.